# Is it mandatory to use contractions in tag questions and the like?

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions, contractions, question-tags

Example 1:

> The weather is hot, isn't it?

vs.:

> The weather is hot, is it not?

Example 2:

> Aren't you going to study tonight?

vs.:

> Are you not going to study tonight?

Apart from convenience in pronuncation, how do the above versions differ (contraction vs. full form)?

Comment: It's formality.

Comment: Of course it's not mandatory, but "...is it not?" sounds either very formal or consciously old-fashioned. I think I might use a construction like "Are you not going to...?" if I wanted to put particular stress on the _not_. Also, I'm sure I have seen "Are not you...?" and the like in 19th century novels.

Comment: All that's needed for a tag question is some question intonation (note that they're always Y/N questions, never _Wh_-questions, and thus have intonation as part of their marker). This is where "Hmmmmmm?" and its infinite variants come into play. Syntactic tags are kludges by comparison, and they're virtually always contracted and reduced phonologically, just enough to carry the intonation. Elaborating what amounts to a question mark is pretty rococo, and correspondingly rare. It is done only for some specific effect, in a few specific circumstances, by a few people. Let's let it go at that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s just extremely common to see tag questions that use contractions as opposed to their uncontracted forms.

A [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) search for `, _v* * * ?` (comma, verb, two words, and a question mark; note that “n’t” is considered a separate word) shows that “isn’t it?“ is much more common (5395 hits) than “is it not?” (334 hits).

Still, 334 hits is not insignificant. There’s nothing wrong grammatically with the uncontracted form. It (in general as well) is just more emphatic and sounds more formal.

Comment: The same  type of questions  are appearing  on ELL andELU

Comment: @JVL You mean the [identical](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225711/is-it-mandatory-to-use-contractions-in-tag-questions-and-the-like) question from the same person …

Comment: @Jason Bassford.Not one  person  but  someother is copying the  same  question  from  the  different  site

Answer (score 4):

Tag's generally use less formal language as a standard because tags themselves are a less formal way of speaking.

You could use the full form if you want, but the tone changes and makes the sentence more emphatic.  Sometimes this change in tone is what you're intending.

For example:

> You knew you were coming home late, didn't you?

... sounds less severe than...

> You knew you were coming home late, did you not?

... which sounds like something an angry parent would say to emphasis the gravity of the situation.

Comment: Tag's what? And who is he anyway?

Comment: @David He is presumably some sort of grocer.